# Why always $x^{\alpha}-x\geq 1-\lambda$ is satisfied?

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials, roots, epsilon-delta

> Prove for any $0<\lambda<1$, there exists $0<\alpha<1$ and $0<x<1$ such that $x^{\alpha}-x\geq 1-\lambda$.

My solution: The maximum of the function $x^{\alpha}-x- 1$, over $x>0$ tends to zero as $\alpha \to 0$. Thus, there exist such $\alpha$.

Even if my solution is correct, it is so ugly. Is there a better way of solving this problem? Any inequality I can use? I would appreciate any helpful comments. Feel free to vote up!

Comment: Experimenting seems to tell me that the theorem is false...

Comment: @Dhmo Why is that false? Can you explain more?

Comment: I think you may have mixed up the quantifiers, ie: For any $0<\lambda<1$, and $x>0$, there exists $\alpha>1$ such that $x^\alpha-x\geq 1-\lambda$. Counterexample: $\lambda=1/2$, then for any $\alpha>1$, consider $x=1/2^{1/\alpha}$.

Comment: I believe so too. $x^{\alpha}-x$ will have a root at $1$. Also, $\alpha -1\ge 0$ meaning that the function is negative on the unit interval. If $\lambda = \frac 12$ then the proposition is false.

Comment: @Couchy311 Sorry, there was a mistake in the problem statement, the correction is $\alpha<1$.

Comment: @GuachoPerez Sorry, there was a mistake in the problem statement, the correction is $\alpha<1$.

Comment: @DHMO Sorry, there was a mistake in the problem statement, the correction is $\alpha<1$.

Comment: Even with $\alpha<1$ this still shouldn't work, because $x^\alpha<x$ for $x$ large enough.

Comment: @Couchy311 $x$ is something to be found. We don't let $x$ be large. Please see the edited problem statement

Comment: Since $0<\lambda<1$ then $1-\lambda<1$ set $\alpha = -1$ and then $x=\frac 12$ works for all $\lambda$

Comment: @GuachoPerez $\alpha$ cannot be negative, $0<\alpha<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(0,1)$ is open, for any $\lambda$ there exists epsilon such that $(\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon) \subset (0,1)$. Pick $y \in (0,\lambda - \epsilon)$. Again, since $(0,1)$ is open, there exists $r$ with $(y-r,y+r)\subset (0,1)$. Let $\delta = \min(r,\epsilon/4)$, meaning $(y-\delta, y+\delta) \subseteq (y-r,y+r) \subset (0,1)$ and pick $x \in (y-\delta, y+\delta)$. Since $x^a \to 1$ as $a \to 0$, we can find $a$ such that $|x^a-1|\le \epsilon/2$, then $$\begin{align}|x^a-x-1+y|\le |x^a-1|+|x-y|\le \epsilon &\implies -\epsilon \le x^a-x-1+y \\ &\implies x^a-x \ge 1-y-\epsilon \ge 1-\lambda \end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add more details for the steps?

Comment: @Su20200 where are you having problems?

Comment: About using open ness

Comment: @Su20200 do you know what an open set is?

Comment: Yes, I do know that.

Comment: @Su20200 An open ball of radius $r$ around a point $x$ in $\mathbb R$ is simply the open interval $(x-r, x+r)$. Since $(0,1)$ is open, every point in $(0,1)$ has an open ball around it contained entirely in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks so much. You proved $x>0$, can you prove we can find $0<x<1$?

Comment: @Su20200 yes, just notice that in the above argument, $x\in (y-\delta, y+\delta) \subseteq (y-r,y+r) \subset (0,1)$ so $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, as $\alpha$ gets small for $x \lt 1$, $x^\alpha \to 1$.  We have  $x^\alpha-x=x(x^{\alpha-1}-1)$  Since $\alpha \lt 1, \alpha-1 \lt 0$ and $x^{\alpha-1} \gt 1$ and having $x$ small is a good thing.  We will certainly get there.

For a proper proof, given $\lambda$ we can find $x, \alpha$.  Let $x=\lambda/10$.  Then we want $x^\alpha-x \gt 1-10x, x^{\alpha-1}\gt 1-9x, \alpha\gt 1+\frac{\log(1-9x)}{\log x}$

Comment: I wish I could choose two answers. Your answer is also perfect.

Comment: @Su20200:  We approached it very differently.  Two views can improve the understanding.  I'm not worried about the points.  Glad to be of help.